# How to determine why Webpack 5 build is slow? (Large bundle file)

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm having trouble with Webpack 5 taking a long time (5-8s) to do an incremental build on any source file change.  This was originally migrated from Webpack 4.

The output section of the webpack file is:

```
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: `static/js/[name]/bundle.${hashVal}.js`,
    chunkFilename: `static/js/${bundleName}/chunks/[id].${hashVal}.js`,
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "async",
    },
    minimizer: ["...", new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
  },
```

Some observations:

- I have a separate vendors generation file which generates most of the things from node_modules.
- The main entry point is a large file (37MB). It appears to be rewritten with every incremental change.
- A lot of individual chunk files are emitted (looks like roughly one per import statement).
- `splitChunks.chunks` with `all` doesn't impact output speed
- I've tried disabled the mini-css-extract-plugin. It made not difference in speed
- I tried creating a few cache-groups for lesser modified sections of code. It made no speed difference.
- I use Babel to transform code
- The [speed-measure-plugin](https://github.com/stephencookdev/speed-measure-webpack-plugin/) shows all plugins as taking very little time (<0.1s), and the overall "output" time taking up all the time. (I removed a "..." from your CSS minimizer config to get this working though)

My main concern is that it appears the main bundle file is always regenerated. I've compared the files and they are always the same, so I'm not sure why it's generated a new one.

I'm uncertain how to figure out what is taking so long and how to go about fixing it.

Comment: got any insight since then?